# Add progressbar to 'load' command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, progress-bar

I'm loading a big *.mat file that takes a long time to load.

What's a quick&dirty way to add a (preferably text based) progress indicator for the 'load' command in Matlab? I found a lot of answers for progress bars in general, however not for the 'load' command.

thanks

Comment: I dont think you can  make a progress bar to load a single thing. Generally progress bars work because you load 500 things so you update the progress bar every time something is loaded. The only way I can think of is by knowing roughly (almost impossible) how long it would take and update the progress bar with a timer.

Comment: And the `load` function is builtin so you can't even hack into it to place some kind of progress monitor. What I would do is do a few rough statistics on how long it takes to load different sizes of files, then when you'll have to load one, you can give an _indication_ of the time it will take.

Comment: thanks for the answers. Is there any other feasible way estimate how long a *.mat file takes to load? It's about 2gb (raw data/frames from a movie file).